# how to hide .php .html extension using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How do I remove or hide php extension? using .htaccess?

2 Example URL :

http://localhost/folder/test.php?id=1&company=ABC&address=AAAAA

http://localhost/folder/test2.php?username=abcd

Thank You

Comment: Please do some basic research before asking. Your question title, typed verbatim into either Google or this site’s own search, would have gotten you plenty of results already.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in `.htaccess` for `html` and `php` extension

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] //for php extension
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] //for html extension
```

for query string add these lines
Try this

```
  RewriteRule ^(folder)/(\d+)/([^/.]+)$ test.php?id=$1&company=$2&address=$3 [L]
```

Try This

```
RewriteRule ^(folder)/(\d+)/([^/.]+)$ test?id=$1&company=$2&address=$3 [L]
```

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)$ test?id=$1&company=$2&address=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)$ test2?username=$1 [L]
```

i have add every possible solution

Comment: 2nd url work fine but for url 1st I received an error.. Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: @twister i have update my answer. check and update if this possibilities work or not work

Comment: same result..if I enter the url with no php extension it will be redirect to this url http://localhost/test?/id=1&company=ABC&address=AAAAA folder auto missing..